# What is the proper RegEx to grab all blocks of SAS code that start with 'proc sql;' and end with 'quit;'?

Tags: c#, regex

I have this:

```
 var blockRegEx = new Regex("(proc sql;)(.*?)(quit;)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | 
      RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

but it only works if the string is on a single line.

For example:

```
proc sql;
create table xtr as
select
    midsu_client_id,
    prodt_cd,
    confmt_ind,
    maj_diag_categ,
    mbr_num,
    pay_amt format=comma16.2
from cr_data.rptng
where &acctnum
and gl_postg between "&date_1" and "&date_2"
;
quit;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RegexOptions.MultiLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) changes the behavior of the '^' and '$' characters:

> Multiline mode. Changes the meaning of ^ and $ so they match at the
>   beginning and end, respectively, of any line, and not just the
>   beginning and end of the entire string.

Multiline is useful if you're passing multiple lines at once into your regex search and you want to treat them as multiple lines (i.e. they all start with '^' and end with '$').

**I think you want to try using [RegexOptions.SingleLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) instead:**

> Specifies single-line mode. Changes the meaning of the dot (.) so it
>   matches every character (instead of every character except \n).

SingleLine is useful if you're passing multiple lines at once into your regex search and you want to treat them as thought they were actually all a single line.

Comment: That is the solution, thank you!  Counter intuitive, IMHO, that if it is multiple lines of text you have to use SingleLine, but hey - it works!!

Comment: Yeah, it seems counterintuitive at first.  That's why I added the little explanatio blurbs.  They at least make *some* sense out of it.